# Links mentioned in the childbrowser not invoked

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins

I am opening a static page in a childbrowser. There are certain links mentioned in the html page. Those links are supposed to call certain function on click. These functions in turn are supposed to open another static page in the childbrowser. But the links are not responding on click.

What am i doing wrong?

Function to open the childbrowser is mentioned below.

```
function openTerms() { 
    var options = {
            'showLocationBar' : true,
            'pageDesc':'Terms of Use'
    };
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showStaticPage("terms_of_use.html",options);
}
```

HTML code for calling the function is mentioned below.

```
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Arial"  size="2pt">6.4 <b>Privacy Policy.</b> This
    Application may collect personal information.  For information on how
    your personal information is handled, see the Cargo Portal Services
    Privacy Policy at  <a href="" onclick="openPrivacy();">https://www.cargoportalservices.com/lmsweb/disclaimer.jsp.</a>

</font></td>
      </tr>
```